# where can we find plugins for Cloudbees jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

looking for some straight forward answer that where can I download plugins for cloudbees Jenkins. Are we going to get it from cloudbess or do we need to use this https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/. Help will be appreciated. I can see -1 but not answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Excactly you get your plugins from the jenkins site.

Is there any problem with using this url?

Comment: Cloudbees is a enterprise version. so can we can use opensource plugins for that? @Torsten

Comment: okay so its a legal not a technical question. But open source can always be used, its more a matter of support.

Comment: I wonder don't cloudbees provide plugins? I am not familiar with cloudbees so

Comment: if you have an enterprise version, just ask cloubees